# how to convert my records in a dataframe into 0's and 1's in r?

Tags: r, dataframe, binary, sqldf

My sample dataframe is as belows

```
p<-c("name1","name2","name3","name4","name5")    
x<-c(seq(0,4,by=1))    
y<-c(0,0,1,1,2)    
z<-c(11,2,1,0,1)    
df<-data.frame(p,x,y,z)
```

I want to convert the above dataframe in below format

```
p<-c("name1","name2","name3","name4","name5")       
x<-c(0,1,1,1,1)    
y<-c(0,0,1,1,1)    
z<-c(1,1,1,0,1)    
df<-data.frame(p,x,y,z)
```

i.e., I want all my records greater than 1 to be 1 and all zeros to be zeros.Please help

Comment: Don't do `data.frame(cbind(....))` - it coerces everything to strings. Just use `data.frame(p,x,y,z)`

Comment: Thank you. I'll keep this in mind

Comment: @Pascal Sir, im getting this error                                                                        Error in sign:df[c("x", "y", "z")] <- sign(df[c("x", "y", "z")]) : 
  could not find function ":<-"

Comment: @areddy - works for me. Try it in a fresh R session.

Comment: @thelatemail Sir, I refreshed the r session and tried again. It throws me same error. Can you please provide any alternate solution

Comment: @areddy - nope, that's the solution. You only need this part of the code - `df[c("x","y","z")] <- sign(df[c("x","y","z")])`  - I think you are also running `sign: ` at the start

Comment: @Pascal - post that as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use function `sign` for this purpose:

```
df[c("x","y","z")] <- sign(df[c("x","y","z")])
df
#       p x y z
# 1 name1 0 0 1
# 2 name2 1 0 1
# 3 name3 1 1 1
# 4 name4 1 1 0
# 5 name5 1 1 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also do

```
 df[-1] <- (df[-1]!=0)+0L
```

Or

```
 df[-1] <- (!!df[-1])+0L
```

#### Benchmarks

```
 set.seed(24)
 df2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:10, 5000*5000, replace=TRUE), ncol=5000))
system.time((df2!=0)+0L)
#  user  system elapsed 
# 0.801   0.061   0.861 
system.time(sign(df2))
#  user  system elapsed 
#1.315   0.022   1.336 
system.time((!!df2)+0L)
#  user  system elapsed 
# 0.602   0.044   0.647 

 0.602   0.044   0.647 
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(pascal=sign(df2), akrun=(!!df2)+0L, times=20L, unit='relative')
#Unit: relative
#  expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval   cld
# pascal  2.184227 2.164029 2.163411 2.142952 2.138964 2.196735    20   b
#  akrun  1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000    20   a
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ifelse` to conditionally assign `1` or `0` to each element:

```
df[, 2:4] <- ifelse(df[, 2:4] == 0, 0, 1)
```